# Facebook share on wall cannot show æøå correctly

Tags: facebook, share

When using share article on my page:
http://www.villaholdet.com/index.php/15-festudvalg/31-festudvalget-mal-rode-tue

... it shows funny caracters instead of æøå.

The share button is called: "Del denne artikel"

Any ideas what to do ?